# Update and select in one pass

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql

I have a table dutyrecord which stores multiple user working hours (subtotal) 
and a UserID (volunteerID). With the following selecting statement I am about to set a total hours for each UserID:

```
SELECT
dutyrecord.VolunteerID,
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( SubTotal ) ) ) AS total
FROM
volunteerinfo
INNER JOIN
dutyrecord ON
( volunteerinfo.VolunteerID = dutyrecord.VolunteerID )
GROUP BY
dutyrecord.VolunteerID
```

Could I combine an update statement with a select to update total hours to each user? I tried something like and some other method with no luck:

```
UPDATE volunteerinfo 
SET 
TotalHours = 
( 
SELECT dutyrecord.VolunteerID , 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( SubTotal ) ) ) AS total
FROM 
volunteerinfo
INNER JOIN 
dutyrecord ON ( volunteerinfo.VolunteerID = dutyrecord.VolunteerID )
GROUP BY 
dutyrecord.VolunteerID 
)
WHERE 
volunteerinfo.VolunteerID = dutyrecord.VolunteerID`
```

Can anyone give me a hand on this?

**UPDATE**
Sorry a few try and other examples I figure out the answer and a more clear way to ask my question.
To clear my question: Can I combine this process into one since I wants to make this process language independent? (I just carry 1 SQL statement in different perform.)

- First, I select a table to give me the Sum of working hours for each person

  SELECT VolunteerID, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( SubTotal ) ) ) AS total
  FROM dutyrecord
  GROUP BY VolunteerID

  e.g. ID: 10001, 1:00:02 ID: 2001, 10:00:34 ....
- After, I want to update the result (total) into another table according to their ID

  update Volunteerinfo 
  set Volunteerinfo.totalhours = dutyrecord.total 
  where Volunteerinfo.VolunteerID = dutyrecord.VolunteerID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this is to first join both tables together then the update and select statement will work in one row. please also comment me if inner join or other ways will increase the performance of this query.

```
update volunteerinfo I 
 join
  (SELECT VolunteerID, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( SubTotal ) ) ) AS total
FROM dutyrecord
GROUP BY VolunteerID) R on R.volunteerid = I.volunteerid
set I.totalhours = R.total
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only updating one field `TotalHours` but your subquery is selecting 2 fields (both `dutyRecord.VolunteerID` and `total`). Just remove `dutyrecord.VolunteerID` from your subquery, and it should work. The new query should look like this:

**EDIT:** You also need to include `dutyrecord` in the `UPDATE` statement since you are referencing it in the `WHERE` conditions.

```
UPDATE volunteerinfo, dutyrecord 
SET 
volunteerinfo.TotalHours = 
( 
SELECT 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( SubTotal ) ) ) AS total
FROM 
volunteerinfo
INNER JOIN 
dutyrecord ON ( volunteerinfo.VolunteerID = dutyrecord.VolunteerID )
GROUP BY 
dutyrecord.VolunteerID 
)
WHERE 
volunteerinfo.VolunteerID = dutyrecord.VolunteerID
```

Comment: Thank for the quick response, an error `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'volunteerinfo' for update in FROM clause'. Also i am thinking the nested select will give 1 set of total hours (for many records with the same VolunteerID e.g. ID:10001 Total: 15:10, ID:20002 Total: 1:01:02). so it'a dynamic update value for each case. Wonder if it's possible